# Have large HDD, Formatted as ext4, labeled as gpt, only 2TB in size still

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

Today to my dismay I ran out of space on a disk in my server, confused as to why I checked with a few commands and I came up with a result that I don't understand.

Checking free space on drives,

`df -h` brings up the following.
[image: df -h result]

Earlier I had set up /dev/sda to be an 8TB partition using `parted`

Starting with a bare drive I did the following

`parted /dev/sda
mklabel gpt
unit TB
mkpart primary 0.00TB 8.00TB`

I print this output now and I'll get the following from `/dev/sda`
EDIT: I have included an expanded parted output.

[image: expanded parted output]

Telling me I have an 8TB partition.

I perform the `lsblk` command and come up with the result below.
[image]

I mounted the drive with `mount`

I am already in the process of copying back data from `/dev/sda` to `/dev/sdc` However, I am stumped as to why my drive only has a 2TB space for storage.

Perhaps I actually made the partition larger than the real drive space as reported by lsblk and this is why it doesn't work?

Comment: You could check that the block size is 4096, i.e. `dumpe2fs /dev/sda1 |grep 'Block size'`. If the block size was 512, it would probably explain the problem.

Comment: I checked this just now based on your recommendation, it is 4096.  This is still very puzzling.

Comment: If everything seems to be otherwise ok, I would try using `resize2fs` i.e. `resize2fs /dev/sda1` (with `-p` flag if offline resize).

Comment: I will try your suggestion when I've finished moving the data back from `/dev/sda` to `/dev/sdc`

Comment: You will probably get better expertise on ask Ubuntu.

Comment: While your response of `resize /dev/sda1` probably wouldn't be a universal solution, in this case it did work to fix my issue.  It reduced my partition size and now I have a 7.2TB partition with 5TB of free space. @J.J.Hakala I believe the messed up drive was the result of following a tutorial that stated to use fdisk to look at the drive size. (8000GB) where as the drive is really only 7.2TB, 7200GB~

Comment: the unit in `lsblk` is very probably TiB, because [8TB ≈ 7.3TiB](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=8TB+in+TiB). It's better to work in blocks unit rather than TB. It's harder to get the partition size in that case, but if you just want a single partition like then just [use `%` unit](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/parted.html#unit), and create a partition 100% of the disk. Also make sure that your partition is properly align to 4KB because you're using an AF disk. But it's probably better to use `gparted` instead of `parted`